# AngularJS error, value not replacing {{clientCount}}

Tags: html, angularjs

I apologize for the poor formatting. Basically, "clientCount" is appearing as {{clientCount}} on my screen, rather than the integer '10'. Any ideas? Thank you!

```
   var app = angular.module('metaDashboard', []);

    /**This is for the meta-dashboard home page
    */
    app.controller('TotalNumberController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
           $scope.clientCount = '10';
           $scope.campaignCount = '20';
           $scope.accountCount = '10';
           $scope.userCount = '100';
       }
    ]);
--------------------------------------------------------------------
    <html lang="en" ng-app="app">
        <body class="page-body" data-url="http://neon.dev" ng-app="app">
        <div class="row" ng-controller="TotalNumberController">
        <div class="icon"><i class="entypo-globe"></i></div>
        <div class="num"> {{clientCount}} </div>
            <h3>Clients</h3>
            <p></p>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Is the app controller wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your app is called `metaDashboard` not `app`, you should change your code to the following:

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="metaDashboard">
```

Also ensure that you have `angular.js` files included in your head section.

**Full snippet:**

```js
var app = angular.module('metaDashboard', []);

app.controller('TotalNumberController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
   $scope.clientCount = '10';
   $scope.campaignCount = '20';
   $scope.accountCount = '10';
   $scope.userCount = '100';
  }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.1/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="metaDashboard">
    <div ng-controller="TotalNumberController">
      <h1>{{clientCount}}</h1>  
    </div>
    
  </body>

</html>
```

I have also included this **Plunker** here for you demonstrating it working:

https://plnkr.co/edit/t80RjCqjmE3y9bOkESo0?p=preview

As an additional note, it may be best to use the ViewModel syntax rather than `$scope` which I believe is best practice and may help you if you ever nested your AngularJS controllers.